# When git fetch I am getting git: 'credential-none' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: git, github

When I am fetching the code using `git fetch upstream` I am getting some messages like `git: 'credential-none' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

Git version : `version 2.9.3 (Apple Git-75)`

What does it actually mean ?  How can I remove this ?

Comment: which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using OS X 10.11.5

Answer (score 0):

This means you have configured your Git to use a "credential helper" named "credential-none", but you have not told Git how to *find* this credential helper.

Probably, something else did this improper "telling" behind your back.  You will have to either finish it correctly, or undo it entirely.  As far as Git itself is concerned, this is not Git's problem.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html, particularly the [Configuration Options](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html#_configuration_options) section.  You can simply delete the instructions-to-Git to use this missing credential helper (but you will need to find out *which* configuration file has this set).  Of course, there could be some good reason that some third-party software tried to set up this configuration for you, so it may be better to figure out what tried (and failed) to help you, and where the *rest* of what it was doing has gone, and restore that, so that this "helpful" (?) third party extension can actually help.

(The usual OS X credential helper is not "credential-none" but rather "credential-osxkeychain".  See, e.g., [this GitHub help article](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/).  It's still a third-party extension, though!  The built-in ones are `credential-cache` and `credential-store`.)